# Modify a data.frame with sub-headers in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a large excel file that looks like the following data.frame

```
Type=c("A", "B", 1, "C", 3, 4)
Description=c("","","DNA1", "", "DNA3", "DNA4")
Gene=c("","","rp1", "","rp3", "rp4")

data=data.frame(Type, Description, Gene)

  Type Description Gene
     A                 
     B                 
     1      DNA1  rp1
     C      
     3      DNA3  rp3
     4      DNA4  rp4
```

In the column "Type" the letters A & B act like header and sub-header respectively. The letter
C acts as a header.
I want to move each one of them to a new column and my data to look like this:
I can not imagine how to define the header and subheaders and move them to their columns.

```
  Type  Header  SubHeader   Description Gene
     1      A      B             DNA1    rp1 
     2      A      B             DNA2    rp2
     3      C                    DNA3    rp3
     4      C                    DNA4    rp4
```

Any help and comment are extremely appreciated.

Comment: I think your example is inconsistent between the blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a way to do it. We use that `header_type` logic to create a 1 for the first blank line, a 2 for the second blank line, and a 0 elsewhere. The 1 corresponds to a header, and the 2 to a subheader.

From there, we can just fill down into the blank rows.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(is_blank = Description == "",
         header_type = (is_blank + lag(is_blank, default = 0)) * is_blank,
         Header = if_else(header_type == 1, Type, NA_character_),
         SubHeader = if_else(header_type == 2, Type, NA_character_)) %>% 
  fill(Header) %>%
  group_by(Header) %>% 
  fill(SubHeader) %>% 
  filter(header_type == 0) %>% 
  select(Type, Header, SubHeader, Description, Gene)

# # Groups:   Header [2]
# Type  Header SubHeader Description Gene 
# <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>       <chr>
#   1 1     A      B         DNA1        rp1  
#   2 2     C      NA        DNA2        rp2  
#   3 3     C      NA        DNA3        rp3  
#   4 4     C      NA        DNA4        rp4
```

**data**

```r
Type=c("A", "B", 1, "C", 2, 3, 4)
Description=c("","","DNA1", "", "DNA2", "DNA3", "DNA4")
Gene=c("","","rp1", "", "rp2","rp3", "rp4")

data=data.frame(Type, Description, Gene, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```